# Magento2 : Cron run not working

Tags: cron, magento-2.2.5, crontab

Below given is **crontab.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="customemarsys_cron">
    <!-- catalog Related Jobs -->
    <job name="custom_product_sync" instance="Custom\Module\Cron\ProductSync" method="execute">
        <schedule>* */1 * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

**cron_groups.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
<group id="customemarsys_cron">
    <schedule_generate_every>15</schedule_generate_every>
    <schedule_ahead_for>20</schedule_ahead_for>
    <schedule_lifetime>15</schedule_lifetime>
    <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
    <history_success_lifetime>10080</history_success_lifetime>
    <history_failure_lifetime>10080</history_failure_lifetime>
    <use_separate_process>0</use_separate_process>
</group></config>
```

I tried to run **`php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento cron:run --group customemarsys_cron`**

But it reflects error

> main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron group: customemarsys_cron, skipping run [] []

Comment: `<use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>` could you please do this change and `cache:clean` and try?

Comment: find any solution ???

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are 2 cron groups by default in Magento 2: **default** and **index.**
Try to change your cron group to default and check again:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
    <!-- catalog Related Jobs -->
    <job name="custom_product_sync" instance="Custom\Module\Cron\ProductSync" method="execute">
        <schedule>* */1 * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

Comment: i want for my custom cron group

Comment: @Parthavi how did you define your crongroup, can you include it in your post

Comment: yes i have included in my post please check it

Comment: I see nothing is wrong , try changing schedule `<schedule>* * * * *</schedule>`

Comment: Do any permission require to acquire lock for cron group? Because the same code is working in test server and not in live server

Comment: no need, try this command `php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento cron:run --group="customemarsys_cron"`

Comment: Still same error generated in log file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92640/discussion-between-magefms-and-parthavi).

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute following sql query in phpmyadmin and then execute your cron.

```
SELECT RELEASE_ALL_LOCKS();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bin/magento cron:install [--force]
```

Use --force to rewrite an existing Magento crontab.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html